# Register Activity for specific kind of Data android

Tags: android, android-dialer

So, whenever any number is clicked in any application, default `Dialer` is opened with that number `pre-filled`.

How can i register my activity for similar thing?.

Where any click on number, will also list out my app and on selecting I get data of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this intent filter to your activity

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls" />
</intent-filter>
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

and add this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
```

[Credit](https://github.com/jdunck/Examples/blob/master/SimpleDialer/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: Dosen't work. Still directly opens default dialer. :(

Comment: where did you add it?

Comment: in my Activity declaration in Manifest.